# Trying to Append search list to my search input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to HTML ,JavaScript and jQuery. I am currently doing a search box, when I start to type text on the search input the search list must appear and able to click the search list name and append it to search input, and close the search list and left with search input and current text that I clicked on the search list.

```js
var $block = $('.no-results');

$(".personsMenu").hide();

$(".my-textbox").keyup(function() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("textboxEmp");
  var val = $(this).val();
  var isMatch = false;
  var nameAp = document.getElementsByClassName("name12");
  
  $(".personsMenu").show();

  if (textbox.value == 0) {
    $(".personsMenu").hide();
  }
  
  $(".personsMenu div").each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if ((content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) && (content.toUpperCase().indexOf(val) == -1)) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      isMatch = true;
      $(this).show();

    }
  });
  
  $block.toggle(!isMatch);
});

function mySelect() {
  $(".name12").appendTo($(".my-textbox"));
  $(".personsMenu").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <div name="selected">
    <i class="mdi-account-search mdi"></i><input class="my-textbox" id="textboxEmp" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="search staff member" />
  </div>
  <div class="personsMenu">
    <ul class="infor">
      <div class="nm1" name="selected">
        <li class="name12" onclick="mySelect()">Malubane Nyikiwe</li>
        <li>nyikiwe.malubane@m-t.co.za</li>
      </div>
      <div class="no-results">no employee found by that name</div>
      <div class="nm1" name="selected">
        <li class="name12" onclick="mySelect()">Chamano Sydney</li>
        <li>sydney.chamano@m-t.co.za</li>
      </div>
      <div class="nm1" name="selected">
        <li class="name12" onclick="mySelect()">Diphofa Tumelo</li>
        <li>tumelo.diphofa@m-t.co.za</li>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's several issues in your code which all need to be addressed:

- You're using invalid HTML. `ul` elements can only contain `li`, not `div`. I'd suggest restructuring the HTML to use `div` containers to hold the information for each item in your list.
- Use CSS to hide content which should not be visible when the page loads. This avoids the [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) which can happen as JS only runs *after* the DOM is ready.
- If you've included jQuery in the page, you may as well use it consistently to make your code more succinct.
- Use the `input` method, not `keyup`, for listening to user input. `input` will also fire when the user copies content in to the field using the mouse for example, `keyup` won't.
- Use unobtrusive event handlers, eg. jQuery's `on()` method, not inline `onclick` attributes. The latter is outdates and bad practice at it doesn't allow for good separation of concerns.
- When searching text, equalise the cases of the search and target strings, don't search for both upper and lower versions.
- Use `text()` to search for the content, not `html()`.
- To set the value of an `input` element use `val()`, not `append()`. The latter is for adding HTML/text content to an element, not setting its value property.

With all that said, the working code will look something like this:

```js
var $noResults = $('.no-results');
var $names = $(".name12");
var $personsMenu = $('.personsMenu');

var $searchBox = $(".my-textbox").on('input', function() {
  var value = $(this).val().trim().toUpperCase();

  if (!value) {
    $personsMenu.hide();
    return;
  }

  var matches = $personsMenu.show().find('div').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
    $(this).toggle(content.indexOf(value) !== -1);
  });

  $noResults.toggle(matches.filter(':visible').length == 0);
});

$('.item').on('click', function() {
  $searchBox.val($(this).find('.name12').text());
  $personsMenu.hide();
});
```

```css
.personsMenu,
.no-results {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.item p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cover">
  <div name="selected">
    <i class="mdi-account-search mdi"></i>
    <input class="my-textbox" id="textboxEmp" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="search staff member" />
  </div>
  <div class="personsMenu">
    <div class="no-results">no employee found by that name</div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="name12">Malubane Nyikiwe</p>
      <p class="email">nyikiwe.malubane@m-t.co.za</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="name12">Chamano Sydney</p>
      <p class="email">sydney.chamano@m-t.co.za</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <p class="name12">Diphofa Tumelo</p>
      <p class="email">tumelo.diphofa@m-t.co.za</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help - note that I just updated the answer as there was an issue in the logic which shows/hides the 'no results' message